# nesting for loop n times to add sublists of a list to itself

Tags: python, recursion, python-itertools

suppose i have a list list_ = [['a'],['b'],['c']] and i want to write a program that that add this list with itself by iterating over each element and then writes the results to a main list
(here n is (len(list_)-1))

this is what i have written so far

```
list_ = [['a'],['b'],['c']]
result = []
for i in list_:
    for j in list_:
        x = i+j
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```

now i suppose if i have a list of 4 sublists for ex list_ = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']], i'm doing

```
list_ = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]
result = []
for i in list_:
    for j in list_:
        for k in list_:
            x = i+j+k
            result.append(x)
print(result)
```

how do i write a function that follows the same pattern for a list of n sublists using recursion or itertools or something better. i apologize if i was not able to explain the problem properly.

i want to use the above logic to rewrite lines 15-17 for `list_`  of any number of alphabets

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

def powerset(iterable):
        s = list(iterable)
        pset = []
        for s in list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))):
             pset.append(list(s))
    
        return pset
    
list_ = ['a','b','c'] 
test_list = powerset(list_)
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
for i in test_list:
    for j in test_list:
        x = i+j
        if len(x)==len(list_):
            if len(x) == len(set(x)):
                list_2.append(i)
                list_2.append(j)
                list_1.append(list_2)
                list_2 = []

print(list_1)
```

desired output

```
[
    [[], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
    [['a'], ['b', 'c']],
    [['b'], ['a', 'c']],
    [['c'], ['a', 'b']],
    [['a', 'b'], ['c']],
    [['a', 'c'], ['b']],
    [['b', 'c'], ['a']],
    [['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
]
```

so in case of four alphabets, the code would look like

```
list_ = ['a','b','c','d'] 
test_list = powerset(list_)
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
for i in test_list:
    for j in test_list:
        for k in test_list:
            x = i+j+k
            if len(x)==len(list_):
                if len(x) == len(set(x)):
                    list_2.append(i)
                    list_2.append(j)
                    list_2.append(k)
                    list_1.append(list_2)
                    list_2 = []
      

print(list_1)
```

output

```
[[[], [], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], [[], ['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']], [[], ['b'], ['a', 'c', 'd']], [[], ['c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']], [[], ['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], [[], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [[], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']], [[], ['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c']], [[], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'd']], [[], ['b', 'd'], ['a', 'c']], [[], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']], [[], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']], [[], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c']], [[], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b']], [[], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a']], [[], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], []], [['a'], [], ['b', 'c', 'd']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']], [['a'], ['c'], ['b', 'd']], [['a'], ['d'], ['b', 'c']], [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d']], [['a'], ['b', 'd'], ['c']], [['a'], ['c', 'd'], ['b']], [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], []], [['b'], [], ['a', 'c', 'd']], [['b'], ['a'], ['c', 'd']], [['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'd']], [['b'], ['d'], ['a', 'c']], [['b'], ['a', 'c'], ['d']], [['b'], ['a', 'd'], ['c']], [['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a']], [['b'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], []], [['c'], [], ['a', 'b', 'd']], [['c'], ['a'], ['b', 'd']], [['c'], ['b'], ['a', 'd']], [['c'], ['d'], ['a', 'b']], [['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['d']], [['c'], ['a', 'd'], ['b']], [['c'], ['b', 'd'], ['a']], [['c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], []], [['d'], [], ['a', 'b', 'c']], [['d'], ['a'], ['b', 'c']], [['d'], ['b'], ['a', 'c']], [['d'], ['c'], ['a', 'b']], [['d'], ['a', 'b'], ['c']], [['d'], ['a', 'c'], ['b']], [['d'], ['b', 'c'], ['a']], [['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], []], [['a', 'b'], [], ['c', 'd']], [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d']], [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['c']], [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], []], [['a', 'c'], [], ['b', 'd']], [['a', 'c'], ['b'], ['d']], [['a', 'c'], ['d'], ['b']], [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], []], [['a', 'd'], [], ['b', 'c']], [['a', 'd'], ['b'], ['c']], [['a', 'd'], ['c'], ['b']], [['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c'], []], [['b', 'c'], [], ['a', 'd']], [['b', 'c'], ['a'], ['d']], [['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['a']], [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], []], [['b', 'd'], [], ['a', 'c']], [['b', 'd'], ['a'], ['c']], [['b', 'd'], ['c'], ['a']], [['b', 'd'], ['a', 'c'], []], [['c', 'd'], [], ['a', 'b']], [['c', 'd'], ['a'], ['b']], [['c', 'd'], ['b'], ['a']], [['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], []], [['a', 'b', 'c'], [], ['d']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], []], [['a', 'b', 'd'], [], ['c']], [['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c'], []], [['a', 'c', 'd'], [], ['b']], [['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b'], []], [['b', 'c', 'd'], [], ['a']], [['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a'], []], [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [], []]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with recursive function that produces N partitions of a given list.  This can be achieved using itertools.combinations by  pairing a left and right side formed of combinations of increasing size on the left side and their reciprocal on the right.  Recursion would repeat the parting process on the right side for each left side combination:

```
def partitions(L,n):
    if n == 1:
        yield [[*L]]
        return
    indexSet = set(range(len(L)))
    for size in range(len(L)+1):
        for iLeft in combinations(range(len(L)),size):
            left  = [L[i] for i in iLeft]
            right = [L[i] for i in indexSet.difference(iLeft)] 
            for rest in partitions(right,n-1):
                yield [left,*rest]
```

output:

```
print(*partitions(['a','b','c'],2),sep="\n")
[[], ['c', 'b', 'a']]
[['a'], ['c', 'b']]
[['b'], ['c', 'a']]
[['c'], ['b', 'a']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'c'], ['b']]
[['b', 'c'], ['a']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
```

You can then use this generalized partitions function (generator actually), to obtain the length-1 partitions of you list of lists and combine the sublist as you go:

```
def partLists(L):
    for parts in partitions(L,len(L)-1):
        yield [ [i for v in p for i in v] for p in parts ]
```

output:

```
print(*partLists([['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]),sep="\n")
[[], [], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
[[], ['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
[[], ['b'], ['a', 'c', 'd']]
[[], ['c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
[[], ['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
[[], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
[[], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
[[], ['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c']]
[[], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'd']]
[[], ['b', 'd'], ['a', 'c']]
[[], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]
[[], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']]
[[], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c']]
[[], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b']]
[[], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a']]
[[], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], []]
[['a'], [], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']]
[['a'], ['c'], ['b', 'd']]
[['a'], ['d'], ['b', 'c']]
[['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d']]
[['a'], ['b', 'd'], ['c']]
[['a'], ['c', 'd'], ['b']]
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], []]
[['b'], [], ['a', 'c', 'd']]
[['b'], ['a'], ['c', 'd']]
[['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'd']]
[['b'], ['d'], ['a', 'c']]
[['b'], ['a', 'c'], ['d']]
[['b'], ['a', 'd'], ['c']]
[['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a']]
[['b'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], []]
[['c'], [], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
[['c'], ['a'], ['b', 'd']]
[['c'], ['b'], ['a', 'd']]
[['c'], ['d'], ['a', 'b']]
[['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['d']]
[['c'], ['a', 'd'], ['b']]
[['c'], ['b', 'd'], ['a']]
[['c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], []]
[['d'], [], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
[['d'], ['a'], ['b', 'c']]
[['d'], ['b'], ['a', 'c']]
[['d'], ['c'], ['a', 'b']]
[['d'], ['a', 'b'], ['c']]
[['d'], ['a', 'c'], ['b']]
[['d'], ['b', 'c'], ['a']]
[['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
[['a', 'b'], [], ['c', 'd']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d']]
[['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['c']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], []]
[['a', 'c'], [], ['b', 'd']]
[['a', 'c'], ['b'], ['d']]
[['a', 'c'], ['d'], ['b']]
[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], []]
[['a', 'd'], [], ['b', 'c']]
[['a', 'd'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'd'], ['c'], ['b']]
[['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c'], []]
[['b', 'c'], [], ['a', 'd']]
[['b', 'c'], ['a'], ['d']]
[['b', 'c'], ['d'], ['a']]
[['b', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], []]
[['b', 'd'], [], ['a', 'c']]
[['b', 'd'], ['a'], ['c']]
[['b', 'd'], ['c'], ['a']]
[['b', 'd'], ['a', 'c'], []]
[['c', 'd'], [], ['a', 'b']]
[['c', 'd'], ['a'], ['b']]
[['c', 'd'], ['b'], ['a']]
[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], []]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], [], ['d']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], []]
[['a', 'b', 'd'], [], ['c']]
[['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c'], []]
[['a', 'c', 'd'], [], ['b']]
[['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b'], []]
[['b', 'c', 'd'], [], ['a']]
[['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a'], []]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [], []]
```

[EDIT] Avoiding duplicates would be better implemented by optimizing the partitions function for it but it can also be done on the resulting partitions using a set (which requires converting them to tuples):

```
def partLists(L):
    seen = set()
    for parts in partitions(L,len(L)-1):
        p = [ tuple(sorted(i for v in p for i in v)) for p in parts ]
        p = tuple(sorted(p))
        if p not in seen:
            yield list(map(list,p))
            seen.add(p)
```

filtered output:

```
print(*partLists([['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]),sep="\n")
[[], [], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
[[], ['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
[[], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b']]
[[], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c']]
[[], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']]
[[], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
[[], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
[[], ['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c']]
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']]
[['a'], ['b', 'd'], ['c']]
[['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d']]
[['a', 'd'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'c'], ['b'], ['d']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d']]
```

Comment: how can i dorp duplicates from the outputs. i care about unique combinations. for example ```[['a'], ['b', 'c']]``` is same as ```[['b', 'c'], ['a']]```

Comment: i think i dropped instances like ```[[],['b'],['a','c','d']]``` , ```[[],['c'],['a','b','d']]```

Comment: yea, my bad, reworking the filter ...

Comment: Fixed now, although not the ideal filter I was aiming to do

Comment: This should work for use case thanks! 
I intend to apply this function a data frame where i want to get all such combinations of df rows within each parent group.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with `repeat=` argument:

```py
from itertools import product

list_ = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]

out = [[v for l in c for v in l] for c in product(list_, repeat=len(list_) - 1)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a'], ['c', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

Comment: Thanks. i think it works in my use case but not sure how to implement it. i have posted full code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

### I think this is what you want:

```
from pprint import pprint


LIST = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']


def indexset(list_):
    n = len(list_)
    powset, difset = [set()], [set(range(n))]
    for i in set(range(n)):
        powset += [_ | {i} for _ in powset]
        difset += [_ - {i} for _ in difset]
    return powset, difset


def mapindex(list_):
    _mapindex = lambda set_: [list_[i] for i in set_]
    result = []
    for p, d in zip(*indexset(list_)):
        result.append(list(map(_mapindex, [p, d])))
    return result


result = mapindex(LIST)
pprint(sorted(result, key=lambda x: len(x[0])))  # just format!
'''
[[[], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
 [['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']],
 [['b'], ['a', 'c', 'd']],
 [['c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']],
 [['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
 [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
 [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']],
 [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'd']],
 [['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c']],
 [['b', 'd'], ['a', 'c']],
 [['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']],
 [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']],
 [['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c']],
 [['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b']],
 [['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a']],
 [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], []]]
'''
```

Comment: This is helpful thanks! how do i get cases like [['a'],['b'],['c','d']] etc.. in my outputs in the above case. maybe i'm not following this completely.

Comment: Are you sure that ```[['a'],['b'],['c','d']]``` is a valid outcome ?

Comment: @rr_goyal yes because basically what i want is all the combinations of subests while have used each element of parent list only once. so in case of ```['a','b','c','d']``` instances like ```[['a'],['c'],['b','d']]``` is one of the solutions and in case of ```['a','b','c','d','e']``` ```[['a'],['b','c','d'],['e']]``` is one of the solutions